# Why doesn't IFF condition work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, reporting, rdlc

I am using this condition to put TICK mark in RDLC report in asp.net but it doesn't show tick mark.

```
=IIF(Fields!fk_PropertyTypes_ID.Value= 1, Chr(82), Chr(163))
```

`fk_PropertyTypes_ID` can return either 1 or 2. If 1 then 'TICK MARK'.

I have selected Webdings font for this expression.

Comment: What is the value you get for fk_PropertyTypes_ID? I will suggest you use the fk_PropertyTypes_ID directly, and remove remaining items to test if the value is coming fine. If it is, then, I would suggest replacing `=` with `==`. AFAIK, you are supposed to use `==` for `IF` conditions, not sure if that holds true for `IFF` as well.

Comment: I'd change the condition to <>, then you're on the safe side in the = or == question.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with the `IIf` expression? If you force `= Chr(82)` without the conditional expression, do you see the tick mark? Also: you could use the `If` ternary operator instead of the `IIf` function. By the way, is `Chr(82)` the tick mark character? Isn't it `Chr(252)`?